# CentOS not finding wifi adapter

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, centos-8

I installed CentOS on a Lenovo yoga laptop a few days ago, but I cannot get the wifi to work. I've tried lots of things following suggestions from replies to several questions on different sites. `NetworkManager-wifi` is installed (and always was). Below are some of the commands people usually ask for, I really don't know what else to do; any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using CentOS 8, kernel `4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64` (updated after install).

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s13f0u1u1u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::210c:8034:2c3b:6a3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a0:ce:c8:0c:26:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 48  bytes 4080 (3.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48  bytes 4080 (3.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:76:1a:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
(base) [cristobal@localhost ~]$ nmcli dev wifi list
(base) [cristobal@localhost ~]$ nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s13f0u1u1u1  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 2 
virbr0           bridge    connected  virbr0             
lo               loopback  unmanaged  --                 
virbr0-nic       tun       unmanaged  --                 
(base) [cristobal@localhost ~]$ nmcli general status
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled 
(base) [cristobal@localhost ~]$ nmcli connection show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE          
Wired connection 2  ba03fe92-ead7-316f-8906-f9563f81c7fe  ethernet  enp0s13f0u1u1u1 
virbr0              9b4f59e0-d4ea-417a-8b33-6052092dc1c4  bridge    virbr0          
Wired connection 1  0a380e38-df47-3546-950a-499be47f5233  ethernet  -- 
(base) [cristobal@localhost ~]$ nmcli d
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
enp0s13f0u1u1u1  ethernet  connected  Wired connection 2 
virbr0           bridge    connected  virbr0             
lo               loopback  unmanaged  --                 
virbr0-nic       tun       unmanaged  --
```

```
$ iwconfig
bash: iwconfig: command not found...
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:34f0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-04-06 19:20:30 -04; 18min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 1835 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 26213)
   Memory: 10.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─1835 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

abr 06 19:20:33 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215233.0594] device (virbr0-nic): Activation: successful, device a>
abr 06 19:20:33 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215233.0907] device (virbr0-nic): state change: activated -> unman>
abr 06 19:20:33 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215233.0962] device (virbr0): bridge port virbr0-nic was detached
abr 06 19:20:33 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215233.0963] device (virbr0-nic): released from master device virb>
abr 06 19:20:35 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215235.1420] dhcp6 (enp0s13f0u1u1u1): activation: beginning transa>
abr 06 19:20:47 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215247.2250] agent-manager: req[0x56232931dec0, :1.257/org.gnome.S>
abr 06 19:21:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <warn>  [1586215280.5142] dhcp6 (enp0s13f0u1u1u1): request timed out
abr 06 19:21:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215280.5145] dhcp6 (enp0s13f0u1u1u1): state changed unknown -> tim>
abr 06 19:21:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215280.5145] dhcp6 (enp0s13f0u1u1u1): canceled DHCP transaction
abr 06 19:21:20 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1835]: <info>  [1586215280.5145] dhcp6 (enp0s13f0u1u1u1): state changed timeout -> done
```

```
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    5.310290] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.316194] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.316198] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.316767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.626347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX101, REV=0x338
[    5.633269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.635529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    5.660332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    5.660495] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.660536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 1841073149
[    5.660579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[    5.660622] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFBAECB7 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    5.660674] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFA0BB232 | trm_hw_status0
[    5.660712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x704BB565 | trm_hw_status1
[    5.660749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x76A93EDF | branchlink2
[    5.660784] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x64DA9828 | interruptlink1
[    5.660820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9415DCE3 | interruptlink2
[    5.660858] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCA8DCE73 | data1
[    5.660890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBC7A6D46 | data2
[    5.660922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6FDAA5D7 | data3
[    5.660955] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF92B9A53 | beacon time
[    5.660990] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1636C796 | tsf low
[    5.661040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF361ED3E | tsf hi
[    5.661073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAA1BF6AC | time gp1
[    5.661108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x27167B44 | time gp2
[    5.661142] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x19B02888 | uCode revision type
[    5.661181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1CFDF695 | uCode version major
[    5.661231] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE59E1DFD | uCode version minor
[    5.661274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1CB0F19B | hw version
[    5.661309] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x55190B33 | board version
[    5.661349] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFDC25012 | hcmd
[    5.661383] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFE6E6A8 | isr0
[    5.661416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7C55ABD2 | isr1
[    5.661449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x30CDD3CF | isr2
[    5.661484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE206E95F | isr3
[    5.661518] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x426E1D20 | isr4
[    5.661553] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5812CAC | last cmd Id
[    5.661591] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFF2FC538 | wait_event
[    5.661628] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x278CDA6A | l2p_control
[    5.661673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD99D0B63 | l2p_duration
[    5.661710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x45AF89C1 | l2p_mhvalid
[    5.661746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x14921CB8 | l2p_addr_match
[    5.661785] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x171A6567 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    5.661823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4D9540B3 | timestamp
[    5.661859] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFC9FD56A | flow_handler
[    5.661945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.661987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    5.662036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    5.662079] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    5.662118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008D49C | umac branchlink2
[    5.662162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    5.662216] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    5.662263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[    5.662304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | umac data2
[    5.662345] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | umac data3
[    5.662386] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    5.662426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[    5.662467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00006076 | frame pointer
[    5.662511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[    5.662554] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    5.662596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    5.663841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    5.665077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    5.666374] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    5.667605] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    5.668812] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A481 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    5.670017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    5.671285] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x728A6409 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    5.672474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD06EEBE9 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    5.673810] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD94B5552 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    5.675162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x02000300 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.676509] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    5.677903] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B16C38 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    5.679346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    5.680941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5fe4, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    5.682118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
[    5.683327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    5.933080] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    5.946316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Answer (score 0):

After much reading and asking people turns out the only solution was to switch to Fedora. Turns out CentOS just works with too old a kernel and the wifi adapter just isn't supported. The reason is CentOS aims for stability rather than state-of-the art.